# An inequality concerning the Fourier transform

Tags: inequality, fourier-analysis

I want to know that the inequality
$$
\left| \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{f(\xi) e^{ix\xi}}{\sqrt{1+\xi^2}} d\xi\right|
\le
C
\left| \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\xi) e^{ix\xi}d\xi\right|
$$
holds or not with some constant $C>0$, if the right hand side is finite.
Here $f(\xi)$ is a complex-valued function.

Comment: What are the conditions on $f$? $f$ is just supposed to be integrable?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Thanks for the comment! If you need, you can assume that $|f(\xi)|$ vanishes at infinity.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net In fact i'm wondering that $\|f\|_{L^\infty} \le C \| \sqrt{1-\partial_x^2} f\|_{L^\infty}$ holds or not

Answer (score 0):

*Here's what I've come up with so far (incomplete):*

Rewriting the LHS and using the convolution theorem:
$$\left\| \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(\xi)g(\xi)e^{ix\xi}d\xi \right\|=
\left\|F(x)*G(x) \right\|$$

Where $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ are the inverse Fourier transforms of $f(\xi)$ and $g(\xi)$ respectively. Then applying Young's inequality for convolution where $p=q=r=1$:
$$\left\|F(x)*G(x) \right\| \leqslant \left\|F(x) \right\|\left\|G(x) \right\|$$

$G(x)$ turns out to be $2K_0(|x|)$ where $K_n(x)$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind that only diverges at $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to Fourier transforms, we want to compare the absolute values of:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\widehat{f}(s)\,\frac{K_0(|x-s|)}{\pi}\,ds \qquad \text{and}\qquad \widehat{f}(x), $$
where $\frac{1}{\pi}\,K_0(|s-x|)$ is a [modified Bessel function of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html) that acts like an approximate [Dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) $\delta(s-x)$. In particular: 
$$\min(0,-\log|x|)\leq K_0(|x|)\leq -\log\left(\frac{|x|}{|x|+1}\right),$$

hence if $\widehat{f}$ is well-behaved your inequality is very likely to hold. Also notice that:
$$ \left\|\widehat{f}*\frac{K_0}{\pi}\right\|_2 = \left\|\widehat{f}\right\|_2 \cdot \left\|\frac{K_0}{\pi}\right\|_2 = \frac{\|f\|_2}{\sqrt{2}}$$
and by [Young's inequality](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Young%27s_Inequality_for_Convolutions):
$$ \left\|\widehat{f}*\frac{K_0}{\pi}\right\|_1 \leq \left\|\widehat{f}\right\|_1.$$